# run time error 9 when setting workbook to array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

SI am trying to set workbooks onto an array. run time error 9.
Here is the code.

```
Dim geneid() As String
Dim venousdata As Workbook
Dim x As Integer
Dim pt() As Workbook

Set venousdata = Workbooks.Open("")
Set pt(1) = Workbooks.Open("")
Set pt(2) = Workbooks.Open("")
Set pt(3) = Workbooks.Open("")
Set pt(4) = Workbooks.Open("")
Set pt(5) = Workbooks.Open("")

For i = 1 To 5
    pt(i).Cells(5621, 10).Value = venousdata.Cells(i + 1, 6).Value
    pt(i).Cells(5621, 11).Value = venousdata.Cells(i + 1, 7).Value
    pt(i).Cells(5621, 12).Value = venousdata.Cells(i + 1, 8).Value
Next i
```

Comment: Welcome back. I see you put in some effort but there are multiple errors. I won't downvote this time but please continue your research.

Comment: `Dim pt(1 to 5) As Workbook`. and then between `pt(i)` (or `venousdata`) and `.Cells...` you have to specify a worksheet reference (like `pt(i).Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there are parts of the answer in the comments and the answer given, so I decided to throw a complete answer on the board.

See the code below that will work (as long as you make the edits for your data / system).

```
Dim geneid() As String
Dim venousdata As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim pt(1 to 5) As Workbook 'need to set the dimensions of the array before adding something to it

'you need to place which file you want to open
'change all workbook paths and references as needed
Set venousdata = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Book.xlsx")
Set pt(1) = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Book1.xlsx")
Set pt(2) = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Book2.xlsx")
Set pt(3) = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Book3.xlsx")
Set pt(4) = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Book4.xlsx")
Set pt(5) = Workbooks.Open("C:\Temp\Book5.xlsx")

For i = 1 To 5
    'the Cells object is a member of the Worksheet 
    'Object, which is a member of the Workbook Object, 
    'so you must set parentage in that order
    'change Sheet1 to the specific sheet for your needs
    pt(i).Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5621, 10).Value = venousdata.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 6).Value
    pt(i).Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5621, 11).Value = venousdata.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 7).Value
    pt(i).Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5621, 12).Value = venousdata.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, 8).Value
Next i
```

Comment: This partially solved the problem. But I still have a runtime error in the following statement:

            `pt(i).Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(5621, 10).Value = venousdata.Worksheets("EFNB2").Cells(i + 1, 6).Value`

Comment: is there a worksheet called "Sheet1" in the workbooks loaded to pt()? If so, what is the RunTime Error you get?

Comment: I had misspelled the worksheet name, and also the copy/destination were switched. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

1. To open workbooks you must give the *filespec* like: `Set venousdata = Workbooks.Open("C:\TestFolder\B1.xls")`
2. You should reference a worksheet as well as a workbook when setting the value of `Cells`:

This code will fail:

```
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.Cells(1, 1).Value
```